# How to get query on two big tables be optimized?

Tags: optimization, impala

The query is in Impala on Cloudera Cluster:

Two tables are involved, one 500 million and the other 900 million

query:

```
create table Citz0063.${VERSION}_pas_prev_ah partitioned by (date_pull) stored as parquet as
select pas.acct_num,  max(ah.date_pull) as prev_ah_date_pull,pas.date_pull
from Citz0063.v201810_pas_test pas
inner join Citz0063.v201810_ah01 ah on ah.id_acct=pas.acct_num and cast(ah.date_pull as int)<=cast(pas.date_pull as int)
group by pas.date_pull,pas.acct_num;
```

Result has 400 million records.

During the query execution, I notice there are 13 stages in the plan and one of the stage generate a table of 14 billion rows.
[image]

Thank you very much. Any suggestion/clue are appreciated.